# Failed to install latest virtualbox 5.2.10 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, virtualbox, 18.04, dpkg, secure-boot

My OS and all packages were updated and functional. I received an upgrade notice for virtualbox, so I let it update. It failed and left my OS unstable.

So I remove it completely:

```
sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox-qt
sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox
sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg --purge dkms
sudo apt autoremove
sudo find / -name vbox             # delete anything found by this command
sudo find / -name virtualbox       # delete anything found by this command
```

Now I have a "clean" system. So I do:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

And it always gets this far then freezes:

```
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.10-dfsg-6ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

I can't even <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>, so:

- I kill the process
- of course then `dpkg` says to do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, so I do that, then retry
- but it gets stuck in the same place
- so I remove everything again, retry, and it freezes there again, etc.

Some notes:

- When I originally installed vbox I [used a script](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/) to sign its modules so I don't need to disable secure boot. I don't want to disable secure boot now either.
- Is there a way I can examine some log to tell me what is going wrong? I looked at `/var/log/syslog` but there is nothing interesting in there.

Comment: I managed to install a working Virtualbox in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS via the method in this link, [Install the Latest VirtualBox on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/), but the graphics stopped working, when I added the extension pack, so it is not a perfect method. I have nvidia graphics using the nouveau driver, and I am *not* running in secure mode (not even UEFI mode, but in BIOS mode). It may or may not be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out that apt provides `5.2.10` but oracle's latest is `5.2.12`.

So I added the key and repository to apt. Then installed `virtualbox-5.2` package. It works.

Not ideal, because there's all sorts of stuff that now wants to remove it and install `virtualbox` instead, and I need to remember to disallow that every time.

But at least it works. Once `5.2` is in the apt repos, I guess I can switch back.

Comment: @sudodus Your link made me figure out this different approach so thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I installed virtualbox 5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 but it does not work. See did not working instruction (if you are interested in it) https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

On my other computer with Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia everything work after simple command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```